# VS Code - How to populate JSDoc for functions within objects

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, jsdoc

I cannot get JSDoc to populate parameters and return types when a function is in an object, though from what I understand this should be supported out of the box.

Example:

```
var foo = {

  /**
   * 
   */
  bar: function(param) {
    return false;
  }
};
```

However, a function or "class" does automatically generate the parameter declarations in the JSDoc:

```
/**
 * 
 * @param {*} param 
 */
function foo (param) {
    return false;
}

class foo {

    /**
     * 
     * @param {*} param 
     */
    bar(param) {

    }
}
```

The only related setting I could find for this was `jsDocCompletion` which I have set to `enabled`. Is there some other config I am missing here or is this not supported in VS Code?

Comment: I don't have an answer, hence I am not posting one. However, the trail to this absence of a feature seems to start here. I am unsure whether a fix has made it into VSCode or not.

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/54619

Comment: They claim to have fixed it here, but I still see this problem: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25783